# Different Results from PDO in FPM vs CLI with UTF8

Tags: php, pdo

Short version is that PDO_DBLIB is returning different results when executed via PHP_FPM vs CLI. The result contains \xC2\xA0 (UTF-8 NBSP), which is reflected when running in CLI but not in FPM.

A very simplified test that i wrote to isolate this problem:

```php
<?php
require('include/config.php');
$handle = new PDO ("dblib:host={$cfg['cwdb']['address']};dbname={$cfg['cwdb']['database']}", $cfg['cwdb']['username'], $cfg['cwdb']['password']);
$result=$handle->query("select SR_Detail_Notes from sr_detail where sr_service_recid=1402978 and sr_detail_notes like '%Computer:%'");
$row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
echo "<pre>Running as " . PHP_SAPI . "\n\n";

echo "Line: {$row['SR_Detail_Notes']}\n";
echo "Hex: " . bin2hex($row['SR_Detail_Notes']) . "\n";
```

CLI output:

```
Running as cli

Line: Computer: bw(redacted)
Hex: 436f6d70757465723ac2a06277(redacted)
```

FPM output:

```
Running as fpm-fcgi

Line: Computer:�bw(redacted)
Hex: 436f6d70757465723aa06277(redacted)
```

As you can see, when running via FPM it's stripping the \xC2 and leaving the \xA0. Environment is PHP 7.3.28 and nginx/php-fpm. Confirmed via phpinfo() that the same ini files are being loaded in CLI vs FPM.

Edit: simplified code to remove PCRE for demonstration purposes

Comment: Although you've said that you've ruled out PCRE, can you just completely remove that from above (just in case someone doesn't read the whole thing) and run `bin2hex` on `$row['SR_Detail_Notes']` itself?

Comment: @ChrisHaas good idea, edited

Comment: Can you try throwing `charset=UTF-8;` into the DSN?

Comment: That does seem to normalize it, with that enabled the CLI output is unchanged but the FPM output contains the full \xC2\xA0. So i guess that's a suitable workaround, but i wonder why CLI is (seemingly) defaulting to UTF-8 and FPM is not...

Comment: I've never used PDO in that form before, but I'm reading things [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-dblib.connection.php#112146) and there that seem to imply _another_ file gets parsed to determine system settings, and maybe that's the difference between the two

Comment: Why are you using dblib driver?